# Spike Arrest policy in Apigee

Tags: apigee, spike-arrest

> Spike arrests aren't implemented as counts. They are currently
>   implemented as rate limiting based on the time the last matching
>   traffic was successfully processed.

I saw the above message in many places for SpikeArrest Policy.

With out maintaining the count,how it will manage to protect  more than allow count.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about a cluster. In a cluster of message processors spike arrest policies work without maintaining message count across all the the nodes. So spike arrest works on each node in a disconnected way.